# How to generate embedding for Image Dataset with multiple features?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, computer-vision, data-science

My dataset has jewellery images. The jewellery is of 4 types:

1. Type
2. Color
3. Shape
4. Material

Now I am aware of converting images to embeddings. I need to group similar images like two plain gold rings are similar but
"plain gold ring with heart shape" is not similar to "plain gold ring with moon shape"

Which model should I use to do this?

What will be my last layer? Will it be the four characteristics, or shall I lay out the number of combinations such as Plain Gold ring, Heart shape gold ring, etc.? Let's assume the possible combinations come out to be 50. Then my last layer will have 50 outputs?

Also a big problem is that the dataset is completely unlabeled. Is there any way I can group similar images unsupervised style?

Comment: What model to choose, how many neurons should be there in the last layer, and whether to generate embeddings or not? The answer to all the questions depends upon the use case. What is the final goal, do you want a model which predicts the attributes of jewellery or given two pieces of jewellery, you want to say whether both are of the same kind?

Comment: @satindersingh yes i want to predict the attributes of the jewellery..also if i compare two jewellery peices, i should be able to get the analysis that ok both are golden, but one has circular stone, and other one has rectangular diamond.